# Laravel project's all assets are giving 404 error

Tags: laravel, apache, nginx, homestead

I am developing a Laravel project. It is under 5.7 Laravel version. I am using Homestead as a local development environment. When I run any route in the project, it doesn't load public assets. instead, it gives 404 error. see attached image below.

I coded correctly on getting assets path

```
{{ asset("public/js/frontend/jquery.min.js") }}
```

[image]

but all these assets are existing in the project folder. and when i try to go any of those assets, it gives laravel's 404 error.see below image.

[image]

It would be great if anyone can give me a solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you loose the `public` part in your `asset()` calls? `{{ asset("js/frontend/jquery.min.js") }}` Because the public folder is the folder your webserver serves as a root folder, so it won't show up in the url.

Comment: Wow. it works. Perfect. Thought it needs to add 'public' as well. Thanks @DouwedeHaan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested by @Douwe de Haan you don't have to use the public part, just call

```
{{ asset("js/frontend/jquery.min.js") }}
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't write public directory to asset function

```
{{ asset("js/frontend/jquery.min.js") }}
```

Also,

> You can configure the asset URL host by setting the ASSET_URL variable
>   in your .env file. This can be useful if you host your assets on an
>   external service like Amazon S3:

```
// ASSET_URL=http://example.com/assets

$url = asset('img/photo.jpg'); // http://example.com/assets/img/photo.jpg
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-asset

Comment: yes {{ asset("js/frontend/jquery.min.js") }} is solved my issue. Thanks